# Limitations of typed arrays?

Tags: javascript, typed-arrays

I've done some playing around with typed arrays using Firefox 4, and have noticed some things.

- The size of `ArrayBuffer` that can be created is an integer in the range `[0..2147483647]`. Passing `2147483648` throws the same error as passing a negative number, passing `4294967296` returns an empty `ArrayBuffer`, and passing `4294967297` returns an `ArrayBuffer` with length `1`. Thus I assume that the size value is interpreted as a signed 32-bit integer.
- While `Int32Array` objects can only be created by default from `ArrayBuffer` objects whose `byteLength` is a multiple of four, I was surprised that `new Int32Array(new ArrayBuffer(2147483644));` caused `Int32Array` to throw the same error I would get for passing an `ArrayBuffer` that isn't a multiple of four, while every other lower multiple of four did work as an `ArrayBuffer` size.

While the first thing I noticed is pretty normal (though somewhat wasteful that signed integers appears to have been chosen), I'm particularly curious about the second thing I noticed. Are these implementation behaviours formally defined in any specification?

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if there were some bugs in such new features.